# javascript is only running once on server for a dropdown but runs ok on my desktop

Tags: javascript

I am filling a drop-down by the user entering some characters it is running a handler which calls SQL to load which then calls JavaScript to fill the drop-down.  It works great on the desktop in VS but when published to the server only is running once.  Don't know why that would happen.  Below is some of the code.  Let me know if this is enough.  Like I was saying everything is working on my desktop only on the server it is not.

**There is a Global hander called Global.asax  this has the routes in it**

```
restRouter.Get("API/Description", "IndexAction", *TypeOf(DescriptionAPIController))
```

**The javascript gets called is:**

```
"use strict";
let DescOptions = {
itemInputId: 'ContentPlaceHolderMain_listviewDNB_Mem_DESC_',
url: 'api/Descriptions?contains=',
size: 6,
focusElementIdAfterSearch: 
'ContentPlaceHolderMain_listviewDNB_Mem_Delivered_Units_',
targetValueElementId: 'ContentPlaceHolderMain_listviewDNB_Mem_ITEM_',
targetValueElementId2: 
'ContentPlaceHolderMain_listviewDNB_Mem_UnitOfMeasure_',
```

}

```
const ROWS2 = 6;

ms.dom.documentReady(

function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < ROWS2; i++) {
        let o = new Object();
        Object.assign(o, DescOptions);
        o.itemInputId = o.itemInputId + i;
        o.targetValueElementId = o.targetValueElementId + i;
        o.targetValueElementId2 = o.targetValueElementId2 + i;
        o.focusElementIdAfterSearch = o.focusElementIdAfterSearch + i;
        new ms.AutoCompleteDesc(o);
    }
});
```

Handler DescriptionAPIController.vr

**This function calls the Iseries**

```
BegFunc IndexAction Access(*Public) Type(List(*Of AjaxData))
DclFld AjaxList Type(List(*Of AjaxData))

AjaxList = CallAutoSearchProvider(LIBRARY, +
RPG_PROGRAM, +
QUERY_STRING_KEY, +
ROWS_TO_RETURN)
LeaveSr AjaxList
EndFunc
```

Comment: Is this for an ie-browser?

Comment: Only using Chrome.

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Can you give us some source-code?

Comment: Please show us your source code and give us some more details like version of SQL Server, what web server software it's running on, etc.

Comment: Is it the handler that fires only once?

Comment: The SQL is coming from the AS400.  The handler does fire more than once.  I know it does work in VS from my desktop.  I dont see any errors with chrome tools Is there a way I can debug the handler while running from the web server?

Comment: @mikems We cannot help  you without some source code and eventually error messages. The problem can be anywhere in your code, so we need to read it.

Comment: I attached a copy of some of the code above.